# Increment Group Numbers starting at 1

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that I am trying to group by 15, then give those groups a number in a new column. What I have works, but it begins numbering the group at 0, and I would like it to begin at 1. How can I fix that?

```
# shuffle the list randomly
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

# specify group size:
SIZE = 15

# create column with group number
df['group'] = df.index // SIZE

# list of groups
groups = [
    df[df['group'] == num]
    for num in range(df['group'].max() + 1)]

# output file
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adjust your line from `df['group'] = df.index // SIZE` to `df['group'] = (df.index // SIZE) + 1`